# State-of-the-art techniques for regularizing Neural Networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, regularization, overfitting, train

For regularizing neural networks, I'm familiar with drop-out and l2/l1 regularization, which were the biggest players in the late 2010's.

Have any significant/strong competitors risen up since then?